# Configure GitHub on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I've configured the GitHub plugin on Jenkins, but while adding repositry i'm getting the below error.

```
Repository URL
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/euphoriakabir/webservices.git HEAD
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have a  proper Git Installation configured in the Global Tool Configuration of your Jenkins insatnce. Verify it by going to `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git`

Answer (score 0):

As @ANIL already said, seems to be that `Git` tool is not properly configured in your Jenkins.

So, you need to make sure that:

- Git is already installed in your system.
- In `Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git` section you have the right path to Git binary (it can be a full path to your binary or just `git` if you have configured the full path in the `PATH` environment variable).
- You provided the right credentials for your repository.